# Cloudflare and cPanel issue - Reidrects back to main hostname

Tags: cpanel, cloudflare

So I setup a subdomain off my regular domain. I then make an A record on Cloudflare to point to the IP address of my server. However, whenever I go to the subdomain, it just takes me back to the main hostname. (So i have sub.domain.com and when I go to sub.domain.com in my browser, it redirects me back to domain.com)

What could be the issue? I've checked .htaccess.

I've had similar issues with cPanel and Cloudflare before where cloudflare won't properly direct to the proper subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult to look at without knowing the actual domain or subdomain in question. We don't do anything that would put a redirect in by default, so it sounds like it may be an issue on your server directly.